# Combining two lists in Scala

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

From 2 lists of the form `List[(Int, String)`:

```
l1 = List((1,"a"),(3,"b"))
l2 = List((3,"a"),(4,"c"))
```

how can I combine the `Integer`s where the `String`s are the same to get this third list:

```
l3 = List((4,"a"),(3,"b"),(4,"c"))
```

Right now I'm traversing both of the lists and adding if the strings are the same, but I think there should be a simple solution with pattern matching.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key

Comment: Is it just me, or does this problem seem easier to solve when you have List[(String, Int)] rather than List[(Int, String)]?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
val l = l1 ::: l2
val m = Map[String, Int]()
(m /: l) {
  case (map, (i, s)) => { map.updated(s, i + (map.get(s) getOrElse 0))}
}.toList // Note: Tuples are reversed.
```

But I suppose there is a more elegant way to do the `updated` part.

Answer (score 20):

How about,

```
(l1 ++ l2).groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.unzip._1.sum).toList.map(_.swap)
```

Unpacking this a little on the REPL helps to show what's going on,

```
scala> l1 ++ l2
res0: List[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((1,a), (3,b), (3,a), (4,c))

scala> res0.groupBy(_._2)
res1: ... = Map(c -> List((4,c)), a -> List((1,a), (3,a)), b -> List((3,b)))

scala> res1.mapValues(_.unzip)
res2: ... = Map(c -> (List(4),List(c)), a -> (List(1, 3),List(a, a)), b -> (List(3),List(b)))                         

scala> res1.mapValues(_.unzip._1)                                                                                                                                                                      
res3: ... = Map(c -> List(4), a -> List(1, 3), b -> List(3))                                                                                    

scala> res1.mapValues(_.unzip._1.sum)
res4: ... = Map(c -> 4, a -> 4, b -> 3)                                                                                                               

scala> res4.toList                                                                                                                                                                                     
res5: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((c,4), (a,4), (b,3))                                                                                                                                        

scala> res5.map(_.swap)
res6: List[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((4,c), (4,a), (3,b))
```

Comment: While I tend to give myself a pat on the back every time I can implement a function without a newline, that's pretty opaque! Can you give some names to the intermediates that would make it obvious that it is correct?

Comment: I'd recommend working through each intermediate result from beginning to the end on the REPL, starting with (l1 ++ l2) then (l1 ++ l2).groupBy(_._2) ... etc.

Comment: As it happens I had - but I'm interested - would you really leave a line of code like that in a source-base, or would you split it with explaining variable names?

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor That's a very context dependent question ... maybe yes, maybe no.

Comment: The group by was a little confusing... I prefer use `.groupBy(x => x._2)`, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

With [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), this is a snap.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val l3 = (l1.map(_.swap).toMap |+| l2.map(_.swap).toMap) toList
```

The `|+|` method is exposed on all types `T` for which there exists an implementation of `Semigroup[T]`. And it just so happens that the semigroup for `Map[String, Int]` is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( (k,v) <- (l1++l2).groupBy(_._2).toList ) yield ( v.map(_._1).sum, k )
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that with this solution, the lists are traversed twice.

```
val l3 = (l1 zip l2).foldRight(List[(Int, String)]()) {
  case ((firstPair @ (firstNumber, firstWord),
        secondPair @ (secondNumber, secondWord)),
        result) =>
    if (firstWord == secondWord)
      ((firstNumber + secondNumber), firstWord) :: result
    else
      firstPair :: secondPair :: result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another opaque <s>one</s>two-liner of questionable efficiency yet indubitable efficacy:

```
val lst = l1 ++ l2
lst.map(_._2).distinct.map(i => (lst.filter(_._2 == i).map(_._1).sum, i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val a = List(1,1,1,0,0,2)
val b = List(1,0,3,2)

scala> List.concat(a,b)
res31: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2)

(or) 

scala> a.:::(b)
res32: List[Int] = List(1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2)

(or) 

scala> a ::: b
res28: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [Miles Sabin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622089/9297144) using `Scala 2.13`'s new [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent (more efficient) of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a `reduce` step:

```
(l1 ::: l2).groupMapReduce(_._2)(_._1)(_ + _).toList.map(_.swap)
// List[(Int, String)] = List((3,b), (4,a), (4,c))
```

This:

- prepends `l1` to `l2`
- `group`s elements based on their second tuple part (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s grouped values to their first tuple part (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**)
- and finally `swap`s tuples' parts.

This is an equivalent version [performed in one pass](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) (for the group/map/reduce part) through the List of:

```
(l1 ::: l2).groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1).reduce(_ + _)).toList.map(_.swap)
```