# How to merge two lists of tuples?

Tags: list, scala, merge

I have two lists in Scala, how to merge them such that the tuples are grouped together?

Is there an existing Scala list API which can do this or need I do it by myself?

Input:

```
 List((a,4), (b,1), (c,1), (d,1))
 List((a,1), (b,1), (c,1))
```

Expected output:

```
List((a,5),(b,2),(c,2),(d,1))
```

Comment: Looks like you are doing the course "Functional Programming Principles in Scala"...

Comment: @michael.kebe looks like they do not change assignments from year to year :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining two lists in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621705/combining-two-lists-in-scala)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try the following one-line:

```
scala> ( l1 ++ l2 ).groupBy( _._1 ).map( kv => (kv._1, kv._2.map( _._2).sum ) ).toList
res6: List[(Symbol, Int)] = List(('a,5), ('c,2), ('b,2), ('d,1))
```

Where `l1` and `l2` are the lists of tuples you want merge.

Now, the breakdown:

- `(l1 ++ l2)` you just concatenate both lists
- `.groupBy( _._1)` you group all tuples by their first element. You will receive a Map with
   the first element as key and lists of tuples starting with this element as values.
- `.map( kv => (kv._1, kv._2.map( _._2).sum ) )` you make a new map, with similar keys, but the  values are the sum of all second elements.
- `.toList` you convert the result back to a list.

Alternatively, you can use pattern matching to access the tuple elements.

```
( l1 ++ l2 ).groupBy( _._1 ).map{
  case (key,tuples) => (key, tuples.map( _._2).sum ) 
}.toList
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can also use `mapValues` to shorten the code.

`mapValues`, as you can probably guess, allows you to re-map just the value for each (key, value) pair in the Map created by `groupBy`.

In this case the function passed to `mapValues` reduces each (Char, Int) tuple to just the Int then sums the resulting List of Ints.

```
(l1 ::: l2).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).toList
```

If the order of the output list needs to follow your example, just add `sorted` which relies on an Ordering[(Char, Int)] implicit instance.

```
(l1 ::: l2).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).toList.sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that both `List[(A,B)]` are ordered according to `Ordering[A]`, you could write something like:

```
def mergeLists[A,B](one:List[(A,B)], two:List[(A,B)])(op:(B,B)=>B)(implicit ord:Ordering[A]): List[(A,B)] = (one,two) match {
    case (xs, Nil) => xs
    case (Nil, ys) => ys
    case((a,b)::xs,(aa,bb)::ys) =>
      if (a == aa) (a, op(b,bb)) :: mergeLists(xs,ys)(op)(ord)
      else if (ord.lt(a,aa)) (a, b) :: mergeLists(xs, (aa,bb)::ys)(op)(ord)
      else (aa, bb) :: mergeLists((a,b) :: xs, ys)(op)(ord)
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't tail recursive.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `foldLeft` and `toMap`:**

Get a map out of one list, and iterate through the second list. We upsert entries into the map.

```
l1.foldLeft(l2.toMap)((accumulator, tuple) =>
      accumulator + (tuple._1 -> (accumulator.getOrElse(tuple._1, 0) + tuple._2))
).toList
```

results into:

```
List((Symbol(a),5), (Symbol(b),2), (Symbol(c),2), (Symbol(d),1))
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `l2.toMap` converts `List((a,1), (b,1), (c,1))` into `immutable.Map(a->1, b->1, c->1)`
- `foldLeft` iterates through each tuple of list#1 `l1`.

  - `(a,4)` of list1 is added to the generated map, resulting to `immutable.Map(a->1+4, b->1, c->1)`
  - `(b,1)` of list1 is added to the generated map, resulting to `immutable.Map(a->5, b->2, c->1)`
  - `(c,1)` of list1 is added to the generated map, resulting to `immutable.Map(a->5, b->2, c->2)`
  - `(d,1)` of list1 is added to the generated map, resulting to `immutable.Map(a->5, b->2, c->2, d->1)`
- `toList` converts the map back to the original input form, i.e. `List[(Symbol, Int)]`