# Scala: How to merge lists by the first element of the tuple

Tags: scala

Let say I have a list:

```
[(A, a), (A, b), (A, c), (B, a), (B, d)]
```

How do I make that list into:

```
[(A, [a,b,c]), (B, [a,d])]
```

with a single function?

Thanks

Comment: just use groupBy

Comment: What do you mean by "a single function"? Using `groupBy` will get you started but there is no single Standard Library method that will make that complete transformation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two lists of tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074031/how-to-merge-two-lists-of-tuples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [groupBy](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/Seq.html#groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]) function allows you to achieve this:

```
scala> val list = List((1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'd'))
list: List[(Int, Char)] = List((1,a), (1,b), (1,c), (2,a), (2,d))

scala> list.groupBy(_._1) // grouping by the first item in the tuple

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, Char)]] = Map(2 -> List((2,a), (2,d)), 1 -> List((1,a), (1,b), (1,c)))
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that gives me a hint. groupByKey is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just doing groupBy won't give you the expected format you desire. So i suggest you write a custom method for this.

```
def groupTuples[A,B](seq: Seq[(A,B)]): List[(A, List[B])] = { 
   seq.
   groupBy(_._1).
   mapValues(_.map(_._2).toList).toList
}
```

Then then invoke it to get the desired result.

```
val t = Seq((1,"I"),(1,"AM"),(1, "Koby"),(2,"UP"),(2,"UP"),(2,"AND"),(2,"AWAY"))

groupTuples[Int, String](t)
```

Comment: Missing final step. This returns a `Map`. OP requests a `List`.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the return type.