# Using groupBy on a List of Tuples in Scala

Tags: scala

I tried to group a list of tuples in Scala.

The input:

```
val a = List((1,"a"), (2,"b"), (3,"c"), (1,"A"), (2,"B"))
```

I applied:

```
a.groupBy(e => e._1)
```

The output I get is:

```
Map[Int,List[(Int, String)]] = Map(2 -> List((2,b), (2,B)), 1 -> List((1,a), (1,A)), 3 -> List((3,c)))
```

This is slightly different with what I expect:

```
Map[Int,List[(Int, String)]] = Map(2 -> List(b, B), 1 -> List(a, A)), 3 -> List(c))
```

What can I do to get the expected output?

Comment: Surprisingly, not a duplicate of [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871691/scala-how-to-merge-lists-by-the-first-element-of-the-tuple), the accepted answer exactly *does not* answer the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant something like this:

```
a.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

or:

```
a.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.unzip._2)
```

Result:

```
Map(2 -> List(b, B), 1 -> List(a, A), 3 -> List(c))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for my purpose. Is there another way to apply groupBy to avoind using the mapValues?

Comment: @ZZZ Since `groupBy` on `List[A]` will return `Map[K, List[A]]`, there seems to be no way around it, because `List[(X, Y)]` will always be transformed into a `Map[K, List[(X, Y)]]` instead of `Map[K, List[Y]]`. So, no, you have to `mapValues`. I've added another, hopefully more aesthetically pleasing variant.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use mapValues, is this what you are expecting?

```
 a.groupBy(_._1).map(f => (f._1, f._2.map(_._2)))
```

Result

```
Map(2 -> List(b, B), 1 -> List(a, A), 3 -> List(c))
```