# How to insert elements in list from another list using scala?

Tags: scala

I have two lists -

```
A = (("192.168.1.1","private","Linux_server","str1"), 
("192.168.1.2","private","Linux_server","str2"))

B = ("A","B")
```

I want following output

```
outputList = (("192.168.1.1","private","Linux_server","str1", "A"), 
("192.168.1.2","private","Linux_server","str2","B"))
```

I want to insert second list element into first list as list sequence.

Two lists size will be always same.

How do I get above output using scala??

Comment: How does it differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859281/how-to-combine-two-lists-using-scala ?

Comment: @srgfed01 - Here I want to add only one element from list B to list A with same index. i.e. add first element from list B to fist element of list A and so on.

Comment: Are you going to post a question about every minor variation, or are you going to learn something from al these questions and answers and do them yourself?

Comment: Also, you don't have two Lists but tuples. Please be clear about whether you really mean List or Tuple, the two are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer:

```
A = (A zip B).map({ case (x, y) => x :+ y })
```

Some compiling code to be more explicit:

```
val a = List(
  List("192.168.1.1", "private", "Linux_server", "str1"), 
  List("192.168.1.2", "private", "Linux_server", "str2")
)

val b = List("A", "B")

val c = List(
  List("192.168.1.1", "private", "Linux_server", "str1", "A"), 
  List("192.168.1.2", "private", "Linux_server", "str2", "B")
)

assert((a zip b).map({ case (x, y) => x :+ y }) == c)
```

Comment: There not list c. Third list is output that I want.

Comment: Yes, `c` is the expected output. What I wrote is a test case. Notice how the last line is an assertion?