# Scala sum Map values

Tags: scala, dictionary, casting

I have a List

```
    val l : List[Map[String,Any]] = List(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2.8), Map("a" -> 3, "c" -> 4), Map("c" -> 5, "d" -> "abc"))
```

and I used the following code to find the sum for the keys "a" (Int), "b" (Double) and "c" (Int). "d" is included as noise.

```
    l.map(n => n.mapValues( v => if (v.isInstanceOf[Number]) {v match {
    case x:Int => x.asInstanceOf[Int]
    case x:Double => x.asInstanceOf[Double]
    }} else 0)).foldLeft((0,0.0,0))((t, m) => (
t._1 +  m.get("a").getOrElse(0), 
t._2 + m.get("b").getOrElse(0.0), 
t._3 + m.get("c").getOrElse(0)))
```

I expect the output would be (4, 2.8, 9) but instead I was trashed with

```
<console>:10: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (AnyVal)
```

I think the exception was trying to tell me that '+' doesn't work with AnyVal. How do I get this to work to get my the result that I want? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use foldLeft function:

```
scala> val l : List[Map[String,Any]] = List(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2.8), Map("a" -> 3, "c" -> 4), Map("c" -> 5, "d" -> "abc"))
l: List[Map[String,Any]] = List(Map(a -> 1, b -> 2.8), Map(a -> 3, c -> 4), Map(c -> 5, d -> abc))

scala> val (sa, sb, sc) = l.foldLeft((0: Int, 0: Double, 0: Int)){
     |   case ((a, b, c), m) => (
     |     a + m.get("a").collect{case i: Int => i}.getOrElse(0),
     |     b + m.get("b").collect{case i: Double => i}.getOrElse(0.),
     |     c + m.get("c").collect{case i: Int => i}.getOrElse(0)
     |     )
     |   }
sa: Int = 4
sb: Double = 2.8
sc: Int = 9
```

Updated using incrop's idea of `collect` instead of `match`.

Comment: @paradigmatic: Not "exactly": with `Option[Any].getOrElse` you'll get `Any`, with `match/case` you'll get the type you want.

Comment: @paradigmatic: Instead of `m.get("a").getOrElse(0)` you can use `m.getOrElse("a", 0)`, but you'll still get `Any`.

Comment: You can use `collect` to get desired type: `m.get("a").collect{case x: Int => x}.getOrElse(0)`

Answer (score 8):

```
m.foldLeft(0)(_+_._2)
```

it's a very clear and simple solution. 
reference: http://ktuman.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-simply-sum-values-in-map-in.html

Answer (score 3):

First, you totally miss the point of pattern matching

```
{case i: Int => i
 case d: Double => d
 case _ => 0}
```

is the proper replacement of all your function inside `mapValues`. Yet this is not the problem, your writing, while complex, does the same thing.

Your function in `mapValues` returns `Double` (because some branches return `Int` and others return `Double`, and in this case, `Int` is promoted to `Double`. If it were not, it would return `AnyVal`). 
So you get a `List[Map[String, Double]]`. At this point, you have lost the Ints.

When you do `m.get("a")`, this returns `Option[Double]`. `Option[A] has method getOrElse(default: A) : A` (actually, `default: => X`) but it makes no difference here).

If you call `getOrElse(0.0)` instead of `getOrElse(0)`, you get a Double. Your code still fails, because your fold start with (Int, Double, Double), and you would return (Double, Double, Double). If you start your fold with (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), it works, but you have lost your Ints, you get (4.0, 2.8, 9.0)

Now, about the error message. You pass an Int to a method expecting a Double (getOrElse), the Int should normally be converted to Double, and it would be as if you called with `getOrElse(0.0)`. Except that `Option` is covariant (declared `trait Option[+A]`). if `X` is an ancestor of `A`, an `Option[A]` is also an `Option[X]`. So an O`ption[Double]` is also `Option[AnyVal]` and `Option[Any]`. The call `getOrElse(0)` works if the option is considered an `Option[AnyVal]`, and the result is `AnyVal` (would work with `Any` too, but `AnyVal` is more precise and this is the one the compiler chooses). Because the expression compiles as is, there is no need to promote the `0` to `0.0`. Thus `m.get("a").getOrElse(0)` is of type `AnyVal`, which cannot be added to `t._1`. This is what your error message says.

You have knowledge that "a" is associated with Int, "b" with double, but you don't pass this knowledge to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you don't know the keys, but just want to sum values you can do

```
val filtered = for {
    map <- l
    (k, v) <- map
    if v.isInstanceOf[Number]
  } yield k -> v.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue

val summed = filtered.groupBy(_._1) map { case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2).sum }

scala> l
res1: List[Map[String,Any]] = List(Map(a -> 1, b -> 2.8), Map(a -> 3, c -> 4), Map(c -> 5, d -> abc))

scala> filtered
res2: List[(String, Double)] = List((a,1.0), (b,2.8), (a,3.0), (c,4.0), (c,5.0))

scala> summed
res3: Map[String,Double] = Map(c -> 9.0, a -> 4.0, b -> 2.8)
```

#### Update

You can filter map by type you want, for example

```
scala> val intMap = for (x <- l) yield x collect { case (k, v: Int) => k -> v }
intMap: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = List(Map(a -> 1), Map(a -> 3, c -> 4), Map(c -> 5))
```

and then sum values (see [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key))

```
scala> intMap reduce { _ |+| _ }
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 4, c -> 9)
```

Comment: While it is concise, using this solution I am left with all doubles. Is there a way to retain the type?

Comment: In this case I can only think about filtering map by some type.

Answer (score 0):

A nifty one-liner:

```
l.map(_.filterKeys(_ != "d")).flatten groupBy(_._1) map { case (k,v) => v map { case (k2,v2: Number) => v2.doubleValue} sum }

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Double] = List(9.0, 4.0, 2.8)
```

Answer (score -2):

Am I missing something or can you not just do:

```
map.values.sum
```

?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. The sum of each key separately is wanted, and the values have different types