# Binary operator with Option arguments

Tags: scala

In scala, how do I define addition over two Option arguments? Just to be specific, let's say they're wrappers for `Int` types (I'm actually working with maps of doubles but this example is simpler).

I tried the following but it just gives me an error:

```
  def addOpt(a:Option[Int], b:Option[Int]) = {
    a match {
      case Some(x) => x.get
      case None => 0
    } + b match {
      case Some(y) => y.get
      case None => 0
    }
  }
```

Edited to add:

In my actual problem, I'm adding two maps which are standins for sparse vectors. So the None case returns Map[Int, Double] and the + is actually a ++ (with the tweak at stackoverflow.com/a/7080321/614684)

Comment: You don't extract the content of the option the proper way. When you do match case Some(x), x is the value inside the option(type Int) and you don't call get on that. case Some(x) => x. Anyay, if you want content or default, a.getOrElse(0) is more convenient.

Comment: @didierd THANK YOU! That was the answer I needed. Can you convert to an answer? I'll choose yours.

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Repeating comment above in an answer as requested)*

You don't extract the content of the option the proper way. When you match with `case Some(x)`, `x` is the value inside the option(type `Int`) and you don't call `get` on that. Just do

```
case Some(x) => x
```

Anyway, if you want content or default, `a.getOrElse(0)` is more convenient

Answer (score 26):

## Monoids

You might find life becomes a lot easier when you realize that you can stand on the shoulders of giants and take advantage of common abstractions and the libraries built to use them. To this end, this question is basically about dealing with
**monoids** (see related questions below for more about this) and the library in question is called [**scalaz**](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/).

Using scalaz FP, this is just:

```
def add(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]) = ~(a |+| b)
```

What is more this works on any monoid M:

```
def add[M: Monoid](a: Option[M], b: Option[M]) = ~(a |+| b)
```

Even more usefully, it works on any number of them placed inside a `Foldable` container:

```
def add[M: Monoid, F: Foldable](as: F[Option[M]]) = ~as.asMA.sum
```

Note that some rather useful monoids, aside from the obvious `Int`, `String`, `Boolean` are:

1. `Map[A, B: Monoid]`
2. `A => (B: Monoid)`
3. `Option[A: Monoid]`

In fact, it's barely worth the bother of extracting your own method:

```
scala> some(some(some(1))) #:: some(some(some(2))) #:: Stream.empty
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Option[Option[Option[Int]]]] = Stream(Some(Some(Some(1))), ?)

scala> ~res0.asMA.sum
res1: Option[Option[Int]] = Some(Some(3))
```

---

## Some related questions

*Q. What is a monoid?*

> A monoid is a type `M` for which there exists an associative binary operation `(M, M) => M` and an identity `I` under this operation, such that `mplus(m, I) == m == mplus(I, m)` for all `m` of type `M`

*Q. What is `|+|`?*

> This is just scalaz shorthand (or ASCII madness, ymmv) for the `mplus` binary operation

*Q. What is `~`?*

> It is a unary operator meaning "or identity" which is retrofitted (using scala's implicit conversions) by the scalaz library onto `Option[M]` if `M` is a monoid. Obviously a non-empty option returns its contents; an empty option is replaced by the monoid's identity.

*Q. What is `asMA.sum`?*

> A `Foldable` is basically a datastructure which can be folded over (like `foldLeft`, for example). Recall that `foldLeft` takes a seed value and an operation to compose successive computations. In the case of summing a monoid, the seed value is the identity `I` and the operation is `mplus`. You can hence call `asMA.sum` on a `Foldable[M : Monoid]`. You might need to use `asMA` because of the name clash with the standard library's `sum` method.

## Some References

- [Slides](http://www.slideshare.net/oxbow_lakes/practical-scalaz) and [Video](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/practical-scalaz-2518) of a talk I gave which gives practical examples of using monoids in the wild

Comment: What does `~` do? I think you should explain the ingredients a bit better.

Comment: for those of us using scalaz 7, I believe the equivalent would be, `~res0.suml`

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I'm going with @didierd though for pinpointing why scala was complaining.

Comment: @JasonMond have a closer look at this monoid thingy, it's useful, I promise! Someone should setup a 'simplyscala' with scalaz on class path for easy prototyping

Comment: I think `~` should be "or zero" instead of "or identity".

Comment: There's an alternative which is `orZero` (I suggested it)

Answer (score 10):

```
def addOpts(xs: Option[Int]*) = xs.flatten.sum
```

This will work for any number of inputs.

Comment: FWIW, to make this work for `Map[Int, Double]`, it's simply `def addOpts(xs: Option[Map[Int, Double]]*) = xs.flatten.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Double]) { _ ++ _ }`

Comment: Indeed. Or the scalaz version which works with both: `def addOpts[T:Monoid](xs: Option[T]*) = xs.flatten.asMA.sum`

Answer (score 5):

If they both default to 0 you don't need pattern matching:

```
  def addOpt(a:Option[Int], b:Option[Int]) = {
    a.getOrElse(0) + b.getOrElse(0)
  }
```

Comment: In my actual problem, they don't. I'm adding two maps which are standins for sparse vectors.

Comment: If you don't have a default for both, you can't use Option in this case, as one or both of them could be undefined.

Comment: What if I make them default to Map[Int, Double] (which is what they actually are) and the `+` is actually a `++` (with the tweak at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7080321/614684).

Answer (score 0):

```
def addOpt(ao: Option[Int], bo: Option[Int]) =
    for {
        a <- ao
        b <- bo
    } yield a + b
```

Comment: This returns `Option[Int]` instead of `Int`. Also, it returns `None` if either `ao` or `bo` is `None`, which is not the desired result.

Comment: You're right that it doesn't produce the intended result of OP's code, however I'd say it does address the spirit of the question's title.

Comment: while it doesn't return 0 like the original answer, simply adding getOrElse will do the trick