# Combining Scala Option[Iterable[_]]

Tags: scala, collections, monads

I'm trying to combine two `Option[Iterable[_]]` into a new `Option[Iterable[_]]`. I would like to return a Some if one (or both) of the elements is a Some and a None otherwise. It seems like there should be an idiomatic way of doing this, but I can't seem to find one. The following seems to do what I want, but isn't quite the slick solution I was hoping for.

```
def merge(
    i1: Option[Iterable[_]], i2: Option[Iterable[_]]
): Option[Iterable[_]] = (i1, i2) match {
   case (Some(as), Some(bs)) => Some(as ++ bs)
   case (a @ Some(as), None) => a
   case (None, b @ Some(bs)) => b
   case _ => None
}
```

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Kind of almost similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617979/binary-operator-with-option-arguments/10618340#10618340, may be helpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're willing to put up with a bit of abstract algebra, there's a nice generalization here: `Iterable[_]` is a [*monoid*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) under concatenation, where a monoid's just a set of things (iterable collections, in this case) and an addition-like operation (concatenation) with some simple properties and an identity element (the empty collection).

Similarly, if `A` is a monoid, then `Option[A]` is also a monoid under a slightly more general version of your `merge`:

```
Some(xs) + Some(ys) == Some(xs + ys)
Some(xs) + None     == Some(xs)
None     + Some(ys) == Some(ys)
None     + None     == None
```

(Note that we need the fact that `A` is a monoid to know what to do in the first line.)

The [Scalaz library](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) captures all these generalizations in its `Monoid` type class, which lets you write your `merge` like this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def merge(i1: Option[Iterable[_]], i2: Option[Iterable[_]]) = i1 |+| i2
```

Which works as expected:

```
scala> merge(Some(1 to 5), None)
res0: Option[Iterable[_]] = Some(Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

scala> merge(Some(1 to 5), Some(4 :: 3 :: 2 :: 1 :: Nil))
res1: Option[Iterable[_]] = Some(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))

scala> merge(None, None)
res2: Option[Iterable[_]] = None
```

(Note that there are other operations that would give valid `Monoid` instances for `Iterable` and `Option`, but yours are the most commonly used, and the ones that Scalaz provides by default.)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
def merge(i1: Option[Iterable[_]], i2: Option[Iterable[_]]): Option[Iterable[_]] =
  (for (a <- i1; b <- i2) yield a ++ b).orElse(i1).orElse(i2)
```

The `for`/`yield` portion will add the contents of the options if and only if both are `Some`.

You can also drop some of the dots and parentheses if you want:

```
  (for (a <- i1; b <- i2) yield a ++ b) orElse i1 orElse i2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this for arbitrary arity:

```
def merge(xs: Option[Iterable[_]]*) = 
  if (xs.forall(_.isEmpty)) None else Some(xs.flatten.flatten)
```