# Using scala Maps to accumulate values

Tags: scala, scalaz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to merge two maps and sum the values of same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key)

I have a bunch of maps of the type `Map[String, Int]`. I would like to be able to merge them taking the sum of the values when the keys correspond. For instance, the standard `++` method on maps gives

```
Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2) ++ Map("a" -> 3, "c" -> 5)
// Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 5)
```

I would like to define an operation that as a result would give

```
Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2) ?? Map("a" -> 3, "c" -> 5)
// Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 5)
```

In fancy wording, `Map[A, B]` always has a natural structure of monoid, but there is a different one when `B` is itself a monoid.

Now, it would not be difficult to write, say, a recursive implementation for `LinkedHashMap`, but I think there must be some trivial and more general way to write this, possibly using scalaz. Any ideas?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this with Scalaz, but it really is a shame that we don't just have a `unionWith` method on `Map` in the Collections API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scalaz has a monoid instance for Map[A,B] if B is also a monoid.

```
> Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2) |+| Map("a" -> 3, "c" -> 5)
  Map("a" -> 4, "c" -> 5, "b" -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are actually trying to use a `Map` as a `Multiset`. For multisets, the operation you are describing is just multiset sum `s1 ⊎ s2`.

Unfortunately, [there is no multiset in the Scala Collections Framework](http://Scala-Lang.Org/node/8192/#comment-34749), but [there are some for Java](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

For a hypothetical `Multiset` in Scala:

```
Multiset("a", "b", "b") ++ Multiset("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c")
// Multiset[String] = Multiset("a" -> 4, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 5)
```

Comment: I never fully understood the choice of terminology for Multiset. They form a histogram of their constituents so why not call them Histogram?