# haskell accumArray equivalent in scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, scala-collections

Haskell has a function `accumArray` function that groups 2-tuples by a key then reduces the values with the same key. Scala doesn't have one, there seems to be one in scalaz but depends on many other scalaz features. 
Is there a better way to write accumArray in scala?
Detail's of this function in haskell here: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputarray/accumArray_f.html

Below's my implementation. Thanks.

```
  private def accumArray[A <% Ordered[A], B, C](f: (B, C) => B,
                                                base: B,
                                                bounds: (A, A),
                                                ll: List[(A, C)]): Vector[(A, B)] = {
    ll.filter(i => i._1 >= bounds._1 && i._1 <= bounds._2).
      groupBy(_._1).
      map(e =>
        e._1 -> e._2.map(_._2).foldLeft(base)(f)
      ).
      toVector
  }
```

Comment: Should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, not so short

```
def accumArray[A <% Ordered[A], B, C](f: (B, C) => B,
                                      base: B,
                                      bounds: (A, A),
                                      xs: Seq[(A, C)]): Vector[(A, B)] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def accum(ys: Seq[(A, C)], zs: Vector[(A, B)]): Vector[(A, B)] =
    (ys, zs) match {
      case(Seq(), _)           => zs
      case(((a,c)) +: rs, Vector())  => accum(rs, Vector((a, f(base,c))))
      case(((a1,c)) +: rs, vs :+ ((a2,b))) =>
        if(a1 == a2) accum(rs, vs :+ (a2, f(b,c)))
        else accum(rs, zs :+ (a1, f(base,c)))
    }

  val (min, max) = bounds
  val ys = xs.filter{case(x, _) => x >= min && x <= max}.sortBy(_._1)
  accum(ys, Vector())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of tuples could be seen as a list of key value pairs. That reminds me of the Map type. Apparently accumulating a Map is possible using ScalaZ: [Using scala Maps to accumulate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496200/using-scala-maps-to-accumulate-values)

I have not yet learned enough of ScalaZ (functional programming) to give you a working example, but it seems you have experience with Haskell and probably have enough knowledge to do this with ScalaZ.