# How to convert a SortedMap to mutable Map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a datatype of the following format:

```
Iterable[scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double]]
```

and I need the following datatype:

```
scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Double]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is to transform `scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double]` into a `scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Double]`, you can do something like:

```
val m1 = SortedMap("key1" -> 1.0, "key2" -> 2.0) // immutable
val m2 = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Double]() ++= m1 // mutable
```

But if you REALLY want to transform `Iterable[scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double]]` into `scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Double]`, then it is a bit unclear what do you expect as result exactly.

Hope it helped!

**EDIT**: then it means you really want to transform the Iterable into a single mutable map. Well, you can do this, although it looks as a terribly bizarre conversion. It would be nice to know why you want to convert that:

```
val m1 = SortedMap("key1" -> 1.0, "key2" -> 2.0) // immutable
val m2 = SortedMap("key3" -> 3.0, "key4" -> 4.0) // immutable
val it = Iterable(m1, m2)

val z = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Double]() ++= it.foldLeft[List[(String, Double)]](Nil)((x,m) => m.toList ::: x)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work. I get the following error: Error:(58, 54) type mismatch;
 found   : Iterable[scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double]]
 required: scala.collection.TraversableOnce[(String, Double)]

Comment: @user3370773 Then I guess you wanted to get rid of the Iterable. Check the edit of my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the iterator first to a sequence, which can then be converted to a mutable `Map`. To illustrate this, let for instance

```
val a: scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double] = SortedMap("a" -> 1.1, "b" -> 2.2)
```

Then

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map( a.iterator.toSeq: _*)
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(b -> 2.2, a -> 1.1)
```

Note the ordering is lost in the resulting `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however using your syntax i get the following error:   Error:(57, 95) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double]]
 required: Seq[(?, ?)]

Comment: It's about the type `Seq[...SortedMap]` in the answer, used `.iterator` and then `.toSeq`.

Comment: I used the exact syntax your wrote including the .iterator. I get the comment posted above

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like a hack, but anyway

```
scala> val a = collection.SortedMap("a" -> 1.1, "b" -> 2.2)
a: scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double] = Map(a -> 1.1, b -> 2.2)

scala> type MMap = collection.mutable.Map[String, Double]
defined type alias MMap

scala> a.to[({type l[A] = collection.mutable.Map[String, Double]})#l]
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(b -> 2.2, a -> 1.1)
```

Convert `Map` to `mutable.Map`

```
scala> a.to[({type l[a] = MMap})#l]
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(b -> 2.2, a -> 1.1)
```

Convert `Iterable[Map]` to `mutable.Map`

```
scala> val as = Iterable.fill(1)(a)
as: Iterable[scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Double]] = List(Map(a -> 1.1, b -> 2.2))

scala> val ms: MMap = as.flatMap(_.to[({type l[a] = MMap})#l])(collection.breakOut)
ms: MMap = Map(b -> 2.2, a -> 1.1)
```

Also note that in this case, intersecting keys will be replaced by later one. See [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key) on how to merge maps with the same keys.