# How to sum values and group them by a key value in Scala's List of Map?

Tags: scala

I have a List of Map:

```
val list = List(
  Map("id" -> "A", "value" -> 20, "name" -> "a"),
  Map("id" -> "B", "value" -> 10, "name" -> "b"),
  Map("id" -> "A", "value" -> 5, "name" -> "a"),
  Map("id" -> "C", "value" -> 1, "name" -> "c"),
  Map("id" -> "D", "value" -> 60, "name" -> "d"),
  Map("id" -> "C", "value" -> 3, "name" -> "c")
)
```

I want to sum the `value` and group them by `id` value in the most efficient way so it becomes:

```
Map(A -> 25, B -> 10, C -> 4, D -> 60)
```

Comment: Will the Maps be always just the two elements? And why use a Map when the values are of two different types? It means unpleasant casts as you can see from the answers. Bit of a design smell here...

Comment: Which one? The `val list` or the expected result? The map in `val list` can have other key/value. I will update my example. Also, this question has nothing to do with real world app design.

Comment: Thanks. But I do think the awkardness of a Map of String -> Any is worth a comment....

Comment: I aware that. Please consider it as a question's challenge :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also using `foldLeft`:

```
list.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0))((res, v) => {
  val key = v("id").toString
  res + (key -> (res(key) + v("value").asInstanceOf[Int]))
})
```

**UPDATE:** with `reduceLeft`:

```
(Map[String, Any]().withDefaultValue(0) :: list).reduceLeft((res, v) => {
  val key = v("id").toString
  res + (key -> (res(key).asInstanceOf[Int] + v("value").asInstanceOf[Int]))
})
```

By the way if you look at `reduceLeft` definition you'll see that it uses the same `foldLeft`:

```
  def reduceLeft[B >: A](f: (B, A) => B): B =
    if (isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.reduceLeft")
    else tail.foldLeft[B](head)(f)
```

**UPDATE 2:** with `par` and `reduce`:
The problem here is to distinguish result Map value from initial Map value. I chose `contains("id")`.

```
list.par.reduce((a, b) => {
  def toResultMap(m: Map[String, Any]) =
    if (m.contains("id"))
      Map(m("id").toString -> m("value")).withDefaultValue(0)
    else m
  val aM = toResultMap(a)
  val bM = toResultMap(b)
  aM.foldLeft(bM)((res, v) =>
    res + (v._1 -> (res(v._1).asInstanceOf[Int] + v._2.asInstanceOf[Int])))
})
```

Comment: the performance is same as in scalaz's `|+|` and `list.map(x => Map(x("id").asInstanceOf[String] -> x("value").asInstanceOf[Int])).par.reduce((map1,map2) => map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k,0)) })` from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7080321/1809978) answer

Comment: it's 40 times slower than your `foldLeft`

Answer (score 7):

A) This one is most readable and performant if you have many items with same id:

```
scala> list.groupBy(_("id")).mapValues(_.map(_("value").asInstanceOf[Int]).sum)
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Int] = Map(D -> 60, A -> 25, C -> 4, B -> 10)
```

You can also use `list.groupBy(_("id")).par...` as well. It will work faster only if you have many elements with same key, otherwise it will be extrimely slow.

Otherwise, changing thread's context itself will make `.par` version slower, as `map(_"value").sum` (your nested map-reduce) may be faster than switching between threads. If `N` = count of cores in the system, your map-reduce should be `N` times slower to benefit from `par`, roughly speaking of course.

B) So, if parallelizing didn't work so well (it's better to check that with performance tests) you can just "reimplement" [`groupBy`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala) in specialized way:

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]() withDefaultValue(0)
for (e <- list; k = e("id").toString) m.update(k, m(k) + e("value").asInstanceOf[Int])
```

C) The most parallelized option is:

```
val m = new scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[String, Int]()
for (e <- list.par; k = e("id").toString) {
    def replace = {           
       val v = m(k)
       m.replace(k, v, v + e("value").asInstanceOf[Int]) //atomic
    }
    m.putIfAbsent(k, 0) //atomic
    while(!replace){} //in case of conflict
}

scala> m
res42: scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[String,Int] = TrieMap(B -> 10, C -> 4, D -> 60, A -> 25)
```

D) The most parallelized in functional style (slower as merging maps every time, but best for distributed map-reduce without shared memory), using scalaz [semigroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key):

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
scala> list.map(x => Map(x("id").asInstanceOf[String] -> x("value").asInstanceOf[Int]))
    .par.reduce(_ |+| _)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(C -> 4, D -> 60, A -> 25, B -> 10)
```

But it will be more performant only if you use some more complex aggregation than "+".

---

So let's do simple performance testing:

```
def time[T](n: Int)(f: => T) = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  for(i <- 1 to n) f
  (System.currentTimeMillis() - start).toDouble / n
}
```

*It's done in Scala 2.12 REPL with JDK8 on MacBook Pro 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7. Every test launched two times - first to warm-up the JVM.*

1) For your input collection and `time(100000){...}`, from slowest to fastest:

```
`par.groupBy.par.mapValues` = 0.13861 ms
`groupBy.par.mapValues` = 0.07667 ms
`most parallelized` = 0.06184 ms    
`scalaz par.reduce(_ |+| _)` = 0.04010 ms //same for other reduce-based implementations, mentioned here
`groupBy.mapValues` = 0.00212 ms
`for` + `update` with mutable map initialization time = 0.00201 ms
`scalaz suml` = 0.00171 ms      
`foldLeft` from another answer = 0.00114 ms
`for` + `update` without mutable map initialization time = 0.00105
```

So, `foldLeft` from another answer seems to be the best solution for your input.

2) Let's make it bigger

```
 scala> val newlist = (1 to 1000).map(_ => list).reduce(_ ++ _)
```

Now with `newList` as input and `time(1000){...}`:

```
 `scalaz par.reduce(_ |+| _)` = 1.422 ms
 `foldLeft`/`for` = 0.418 ms
 `groupBy.par.mapValues` = 0.343 ms
```

And it's better to choose `groupBy.par.mapValues` here.

3) Finally, let's define another aggregation:

```
scala> implicit class RichInt(i: Int){ def ++ (i2: Int) = { Thread.sleep(1); i + i2}}
defined class RichInt
```

And test it with `list` and `time(1000)`:

```
`foldLeft` = 7.742 ms
`most parallelized` = 3.315 ms
```

So it's better to use most parallelized version here.

---

Why reduce is so slow:

Let's take 8 elements. It produces a calculation tree from leafs `[1] + ... + [1]` to root `[1 + ... + 1]`:

```
time(([1] + [1]) + ([1] + [1]) + ([1] + [1]) + ([1] + [1]) 
   => ([1 +1] + [1 +1]) + ([1 + 1] + [1 + 1]) 
   => [1 + 1 + 1 + 1] + [1 + 1 + 1 + 1]) 
 = (1 + 1 + 1 + 1) +  (2 + 2) + 4 = 12
```

time(N = 8) = 8/2 + 2*8/4 + 4*8/8 = 8 * (1/2 + 2/4 + 4/8) = 8 * log2(8)/ 2 = 12

Or just:

[image: time(N) = N * log2(N)/2]

Of course this formula works only for numbers that are actually powers of 2. Anyway, the complexity is `O(NlogN)`, which is slower than `foldLeft`'s `O(N)`. Even after parallelization it becomes just `O(N)` so this implementation can be used only for Big Data's distributed Map-Reduce, or simply saying when you have no enough memory and are storing your Map in some cache.

You may notice that it's parallelizing better than other options for your input - that's just because for 6 elements it's not so slow (almost `O(1)` here) - and you do only one reduce call - when other options are grouping data before or just creating more threads, which leads to more "thread switching" overhead. Simply saying, `reduce` creates less threads here. But if you have more data - it doesn't work of course (see experiment 2).

Comment: I want to say "you again" but it will sound cliche :). Anyway, which one is better between `list.par.groupBy(_("id")).mapValues(_.map(_("value").asInstanceOf[Int]).sum)` and `list.groupBy(_("id")).par.mapValues(_.map(_("value").asInstanceOf[Int]).sum)`?

Comment: shortly, it depends on your collection - so it's better to run performance tests to choose appropriate solution.

Comment: As always, your answer always bring something new to me :). Just a bit suggestion: don't use `map` for variable name e.g. `val map`, it can be mistaken with map method.

Comment: Ok. What would you say about one-letter naming :) http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs3161/14s2/StyleGuide.html (I know, Scala isn't Haskell)

Comment: I'm fine with that :)

Comment: Awesome update :). So this one is the badass? `for + update without mutable map initialization = 0.00105`, but where is the code?

Comment: this (version from my answer with `for (e <- list; `...) is most efficient for your input as long as `foldLeft` from another answer. But other versions are better for bigger inputs.

Comment: I'm confused at `without mutable map initialization`, does it mean don't use mutable map and being initialized, or just don't initialize it with `withDefaultValue`?

Comment: it means that i didn't count the time for `val m = mutable.Map` here, as long as i excluded the time for `.par` itself in `without parallell collection init `. If you have big collection - they will be less significant

Comment: Ah, I see. Btw was the `list.par.groupBy` version included in the test?

Comment: I called it `groupBy.par.mapValues`

Comment: it's the best choice if you have a collection, where one id has many many elements to sum (see option 2 in testsing)

Comment: So `list.groupBy.par` and `list.par.groupBy` are roughly equal in performance? Also, is it possible to do with `reduceLeft`? I think I heard somewhere that reduce is better in performance than fold.

Comment: Oops sorry, misread - added `list.par.groupBy` it's equal `list.par.groupBy.par` but twice slower than `list.groupBy.par` (for your input).

Comment: as far as I can see [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala) - no big difference. But `reduce` itself should be faster for parallell collections. It's possible to implement it with reduce, but you will have to merge maps for that - I've added example with scalaz semigroups, but it's not so fast.

Comment: * `reduce` is parallelizable,  `reduceLeft` - isn't

Comment: That's interesting, can you show me how it looks like if using `reduce`? Also, how could reduceLeft isn't parallelizable? Looking from the source code, reduce invoke reduceLeft.

Comment: it's not source code for parallell collection - just try `List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).par.reduce((a, b) => {println(a + " " + b); a + b})` (execute it several times) - and compare them. I've already updated the answer with reduce example (see, D). reduce is working with semigroups, which means associativity of some "+" operation, which means order doesn't matter here. reduceLeft is executing operations in the same order as elements are present inside list.

Comment: What does |+| mean? Is it possible to solve with plain `reduce` without using scalaz? (just curious here, sorry for troubling)

Comment: yes - you have to implement merging two maps with summing elements with same keys by yourself then

Comment: about |+| - see the link attached to "semigroups" word in my answer, you'll find some implementations there

Comment: So the map merging would make the process slower?

Comment: Could you explain how `[1 + 1 + 1 + 1] + [1 + 1 + 1 + 1])` can turn into `(1 + 1 + 1 + 1) +  (2 + 2) + 4`? (sorry for prolonging the comment chats, but i'm so curious here)

Comment: anyway, the right answer to your question was `foldLeft` (i'd prefer to remove reduce/reduceLeft from it as they are redundand). I've just demonstrated that parallelizing won't work for your small collection, and not much usable even for bigger collections, as "+" operation is pretty fast.

Comment: pay attention to closing parenthesis - `[1 + 1 + 1 + 1] + [1 + 1 + 1 + 1]` is turning into `4` as you need 4 operations to merge maps with 4 elements each. `=>` means piping results from one level to another - i'm not good at pseudographics - just imagine the tree from leafs `[1] + ... + [1]` to root `[1 + ... + 1]`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I actually planned to let the community choose the answer (I'll award whoever getting highest votest by 2-3 votes diff) since foldleft and your answer are spot on for small data & big data, but if you say so... Btw, the `"+" operations is pretty fast`, did you refer to the `for + update` code?

Comment: I refer just to simple + from 2 + 2 = 4))

Comment: Sorry - have no time - you can use my `time` function free - it's not proprietary :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for troubling. Thanks for the answer. Really appreciate your contribution :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about "most efficient", but the nicest way I can think of is using scalaz `suml`, which uses `Monoid`; the `Monoid` for `Map` does exactly what you want. The only ugly part is turning those `Map[String, Any]`s into something more well-typed and representing the structure we want (e.g. `Map("A" → 20)`).

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
list.map{m => 
  Map(m("id").asInstanceOf[String] → m("value").asInstanceOf[Int])
}.suml
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you can use the [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a `reduce` step:

```
// val list = List(Map("id" -> "A", "value" -> 20, "name" -> "a"), Map("id" -> "B", "value" -> 10, "name" -> "b"), Map("id" -> "A", "value" -> 5, "name" -> "a"), Map("id" -> "C", "value" -> 1, "name" -> "c"), Map("id" -> "D", "value" -> 60, "name" -> "d"), Map("id" -> "C", "value" -> 3, "name" -> "c"))
list.groupMapReduce(_("id"))(_("value").asInstanceOf[Int])(_ + _)
// Map("A" -> 25, "B" -> 10, "C" -> 4, "D" -> 60)
```

This:

- `group`s Maps by their "id" field (`_("id")`) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped Map to their "value" field typed back to Int (`_("value").asInstanceOf[Int]`) (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within each group (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
list.groupBy(_("id")).mapValues(_.map(_("value").asInstanceOf[Int]).reduce(_ + _)).toMap
```