# how to join two hashmaps by a key in spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have two RDD each in the format of

> {string, HashMap[long,object]}

I want to perform a join operation on them such that the hashmap of the same key get merge in scala.

```
RDD1-> {string1,HashMap[{long a,object},{long b,object}]
RDD2-> {string1,HashMap[{long c,object}]
```

After joining the two RDD, it should be like

```
RDD->{string1,HashMap[{long a,object},{long b,object},{long c,object}]
```

Any help will be appreciated, also I am kind of new to scala and spark.

Comment: how are you planning to deal with keys that are in both hashmaps?

Comment: the value corresponding to both keys will be same in the hashmap, in case there are keys with same value in both hashmap so even if they overlap their shouldn't be an issue(they shouldnt have duplicate entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by joining the two RDDs and applying a merge function to the tuples of maps:

> def join[W](other: RDD[(K, W)], numSplits: Int): RDD[(K, (V, W))]
>   Return an RDD containing all pairs of elements with matching keys in
>   this and other. Each pair of elements will be returned as a (k, (v1,
>   v2)) tuple, where (k, v1) is in this and (k, v2) is in other. Performs
>   a hash join across the cluster.
>
> def mapValues[U](f: (V) ⇒ U): RDD[(K, U)] Pass each value in the
>   key-value pair RDD through a map function without changing the keys;
>   this also retains the original RDD's partitioning.

assume, there is a function merge like discussed in [Best way to merge two maps and sum the values of same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key)

```
def [K] merge(a:K,b:K):K = ???
```

could be like

```
def merge(a:Map[K,V],b:Map[K,V]) = a ++ b
```

given that, the RDDs can be joined first

```
val joined = RDD1.join(RDD2)
```

and then mapped

```
val mapped = joined.mapValues( v => merge(v._1,v._2))
```

The result is an RDD with (Key, the merged Map)..

Comment: This code is merging the maps with the common keys in both rdds, but is filtering out the rest. I worked it around by doing the union of this and the orginal RDD, still it helped in fixing the solution thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: a simpler way is just to take the union and then reduce by key:

```
(rdd1 union rdd2).reduceByKey(_++_)
```

**Older solution, just for reference**. This can also be done by `cogroup`, which collects values for keys in one or both RDDs (whereas `join` will omit values that only have a key in one of the original RDDs). See the [ScalaDoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).

We then concatenate the lists of values using `++` to form a single list of values, and finally `reduce` the values (Maps) to a single Map.

The last two steps can be combined into a single `mapValues` operation:

Using this data...

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("a"->Map(1->"one", 2->"two")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List("a"->Map(3->"three")))
```

...in the spark shell:

```
val x = (rdd1 cogroup rdd2).mapValues{ case (a,b) => (a ++ b).reduce(_++_)}

x foreach println

> (a,Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two, 3 -> three))
```