# Scala concatenate maps from a list

Tags: scala, dictionary, fold

Having `val mapList: List[Map[String, Int]]`, I want to do something like:

```
val map = mapList foldLeft (Map[String, Int]()) ( _ ++ _ )
```

or

```
val map = mapList foldLeft (Map[String, Int]())
 ( (m1: Map[String, Int], m2: Map[String, Int]) => m1 ++ m2 )
```

Neither option is compiled (first says "missing parameter type for expanded function `(x, y) => x ++ y`" and second says "type mismatch; found `(Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int]) => Map[String, Int];` required: `String`").

I want to achieve a classical solution for concatenating a list of immutable maps such as `List( Map("apple" -> 5, "pear" -> 7), Map("pear" -> 3, "apricot" -> 0) )` would produce a `Map("apple" -> 5, "pear" -> 10, "apricot" -> 0)`.

Using scala `2.10.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a dot before `foldLeft`.  You can only use spaces instead of dots under specialized conditions, such as for methods with exactly 1 parameter (arity-1 methods):

```
val map = mapList.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) ( _ ++ _ )
```

You can read more about method invocation best practices [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html).

You might also be interested in the `reduce` methods, which are specialized versions of the `fold` methods, where the return type is the same as the type of the elements of the collection.  For example `reduceLeft` uses the first element of the collection as a seed for the `foldLeft`.  Of course, since this relies on the first element's existence, it will throw an exception if the collection is empty.  Since `reduceLeft` takes only 1 parameter, you can more easily use a space to invoke the method:

```
mapList.reduceLeft( _ ++ _)
mapList reduceLeft(_ ++ _)
```

Finally, you should note that all you are doing here is merging the maps.  When using `++` to merge the maps, you will just override keys that are already present in the map – you won't be adding the values of duplicate keys.  If you wanted to do that, you could follow the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key), and apply them to the `foldLeft` or `reduceLeft`.  For example:

```
mapList reduceLeft { (acc, next) => 
    (acc.toList ++ next.toList).groupBy(_._1).toMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum) 
}
```

Or slightly differently:

```
mapList.map(_.toSeq).reduceLeft(_ ++ _).groupBy(_._1).toMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

And, if you're using Scalaz, then most concisely:

```
mapList reduceLeft { _ |+| _ }
```

Comment: You can use it for arity-1 methods or arity-0 methods (although the latter is discouraged usually).   You can't use it for methods with multiple parameters or multiple parameter lists.

Comment: Even more concisely with scalaz: `mapList.suml`.