# How to convert from scala Map to scala.collection.immutable.HashMap?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

For some weird reason, there is this one method `merged` that is only declared in `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap` but not in generic `Map` trait (perhaps its implementation makes it very unpalatable to other `Map` implementations?).

So I need to convert my `Map[A, B]` to `HashMap[A, B]` and so far I cannot find an easy way to do so. This is my current implementation to *hack* around `def to[Col[_]]` which expects unary higher-kind instead of binary higher-kind.

```
val m1 = Map("foo" -> 1)
val m2 = Map("foo" -> 2, "bar" -> 2)

type HM[_] = HashMap[String, Int]
(m1.to[HM] merged m2.to[HM]) { case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => (k1, v1 + v2) } // Map("foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 2)
```

It works as expected but I can't help but to think there must be a better way to convert from `Map` to `HashMap` (given it's the default implementation).

Or perhaps in more general, better way to access default implementation of scala collection generic traits?

Comment: Maybe `HashMap(m1.toSeq: _*)`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key for other options to merge maps.

Comment: If you use operations that are only available in `HashMap`, why not declare your maps as `HashMap` in the first place?

Comment: @Łukasz Yeah I've seen that question but this portion of my code is very performance sensitive and using `toSeq` will require 2 iterations. On the same note, `merged` is supposedly very efficient so it'd be nice to use it.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn Because I get those map by calling `toMap` on array. I can fold it manually to `HashMap` but rather not to if possible.

Comment: So if you want to be fast you probably want to take your array and do `HashMap.empty[String, Int] ++ array`. To do this inline you will need to help type inference to not get a plain `Map` again. `((HashMap.empty ++ array): HashMap[String, Int]) merged ...`

Comment: Why not directly convert your arrays to an `HashMap` then (using `to` just like you do here)? Is there a point in creating an intermediate `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an empty HashMap and add all elements there:

```
immutable.HashMap.empty ++= yourMap
```

Comment: OP wanted `immutable.HashMap`

Comment: @Łukasz: fixed, also not much difference there

Comment: That should be just `++`, not `++=`.

Answer (score 0):

This will not answer your question, but it is a solution to your problem.
It will be faster just to:

1. Implement the `merged` method that you need for map,
2. Use the `++` method defined on map to make a merge.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do the conversion, assuming the original map is already a `immutable.HashMap`, is `immutable.HashMap.from(originalMap)` because it returns the original map when it is already a `immutable.HashMap`.

But consider that the `immutable.Map` constructor builds an `immutable.HashMap` only if the size is greater than 4.

```scala
scala> val generic4 = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3,  "d" -> 4)
val generic4: Map[String, Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)

scala> generic4.getClass
val res5: Class[? <: Map[String, Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4

scala> val generic5 = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3,  "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5)
val generic5: Map[String, Int] = HashMap(e -> 5, a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)

scala> generic5.getClass
val res6: Class[? <: Map[String, Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

scala> val specific5 = HashMap.from(generic5)
val specific5: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String, Int] = HashMap(e -> 5, a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)

scala> specific5 eq generic5
val res7: Boolean = true
```