# How to sum a map of maps of same key in scala

Tags: scala, merge, maps, scalaz

I have the following map of maps :

```
var map1 : mutable.Map[String, Map[String, Double]]
map1("U1" -> ("a"-> 2.1, "b"->3.21, "c"->7.1), 
     "U2" -> ("a"-> 3.1, "b"->12.1, "c"->1.4)
    )
```

I want to traverse through this map and merge all the values in a way that i get the following:

```
finalMap = ("a"->5.2, "b"->15.22, "c"->8.5)
```

I came across the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key) and imported scalaz for the solution but I'm a little unclear as to how to use the `|+|` on the values iterable.

I'm using the following code :

```
finalMap : Map[String, Double]()
map1.values.foreach{ (valueMap : Map[String, Double]) => 
  finalMap  |+| valueMap 
}
```

Any pointers on how to correct this

Comment: "Any pointers on how to correct this" First, you need to tell us what needs correcting. What problem are you getting? (but for a started, you're merging each map with `finalMap` then throwing away the result, as `foreach` doesn't return a value)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, I think he wants to sum maps values that have same key. And also his answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key

Comment: @Ionut, yes that's obvious. What isn't obvious is "what needs correcting" as I said in my comment. We shouldn't be asked to work out what the symptoms are before suggesting a solution.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thanks for the comment, will keep that in mind for future.

Comment: @Ionut I have obviously researched on this answer and it has been linked in the question itself, my question was more on how to tweak the answer for my particular case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement *dhg*'s answer :

First, to use `|+|` on a `Map[A, B]` we need a `Semigroup[B]` instance. In this case `Semigroup[Double]`. But scalaz itself doesn't give you this instance, because it wouldn't follow the rules/laws of a correct `Semigroup` instance ([related scalaz issue](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/334)).

No despair, because we can still get an instance from the project [scalaz-outlaws](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-outlaws) (which only supports scalaz 7.1.x it seems). Using the `Double` outlaw instance we can now combine two `Double`s, while ignoring the deprecation message urging us not to use `Monoid[Double]` because it doesn't uphold the laws :

```
import scalaz.syntax.semigroup._
import scalaz.outlaws.std.double._

1.0 |+| 2.0
// <console>:18: warning: value doubleMonoid in trait DoubleOutlawInstances 
// is deprecated: Monoid[Double] violates the associativity law
//        1.0 |+| 2.0
//        ^
// res0: Double = 3.0
```

Second, we can simplify the `reduce` / `fold` with scalaz by using the `Monoid[Double]` implicitly instead of using `|+|` directly.

```
import scalaz.std.map._
import scalaz.outlaws.std.double._
import scalaz.syntax.foldable._

val map = Map("U1" -> Map("a"-> 2.1, "b"->3.21, "c"->7.1), 
              "U2" -> Map("a"-> 3.1, "b"->12.1, "c"->1.4))

map.concatenate
// Map[String,Double] = Map(a -> 5.2, b -> 15.309999999999999, c -> 8.5)
```

The `map.concatenate` is analogous to

```
map.values.fold(Monoid[Map[String, Double]].zero)(_ |+| _)
```

Comment: I get the exception "object outlaws is not a member of package scalaz" even after changing my scalaz version to 7.1.8 (Also tried it on 7.1.1). Any particular version on which this should be available.

Comment: @hbabbar did you add the *scalaz-outlaws* dependency I linked to ?

Comment: How did I not know about `concatenate`?

Comment: @PeterNeyens Is the concatenate method not present in scalaz-outlaws_2.10?

Comment: `concatenate` is scalaz itself in [`FoldableSyntax`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/FoldableSyntax.scala#L71).

Comment: @PeterNeyens Also, on using map.values.fold(Monoid[Map[String, Double]].zero)(_ |+| _), I get the exception "value |+| is not a member of Map[String,Double]"

Comment: Which version of scalaz are you using ? Does `ToFoldableOpsUnapply(map).concatenate` work ?  Which imports are you using with the `fold` / `|+|` ?

Comment: I probably tested `map.concatenate` with the [si2712-fix compiler plugin](https://github.com/milessabin/si2712fix-plugin), without the plugin possible solutions are to use the `ToFoldableOpsUnapply` I showed above, or use a type alias : `type StringMap[A] = Map[String, A]` with then `(map: StringMap[StringMap[Double]]).concatenate` or `Foldable[StringMap].fold(map)` or concatenate the values :`map.values.toList.concatenate`.

Comment: @PeterNeyens I'm trying to use scalaz_outlaws_2.10 version 3. It is working on scalaz_outlaws_2.11 version 3 but for some spark build related issues we are forced to use 2.10 version. Also ToFoldableOpsUnapply(map).concatenate doesnt work with 2_10.

I'm using the following imports:
import scalaz.std.map._
import scalaz.outlaws.std.double._
import scalaz.syntax.foldable._

Answer (score 1):

First, use `val`s and immutable data structures.  Second, look up how to initialize collections; there are many, many examples on the web.

```
val map1 = Map("U1" -> Map("a"-> 2.1, "b"->3.21, "c"->7.1), 
               "U2" -> Map("a"-> 3.1, "b"->12.1, "c"->1.4))
```

Finally, what you are trying to do is `reduce` all of the `Map`s in `values` into a single `Map`.  You can do that like this:

```
val finalMap = map1.values.reduce(_ |+| _)
// finalMap: Map[String,Double] = Map(a -> 5.2, b -> 15.31, c -> 8.5)
```

If you think that `map1` might be empty, then use `fold` instead, which is basically a `reduce` in which you give an initial value:

```
map1.values.fold(Map.empty)(_ |+| _)
// res0: Map[String,Double] = Map(a -> 5.2, b -> 15.31, c -> 8.5)

val emptyMap = Map.empty[String, Map[String, Double]]
emptyMap.values.fold(Map.empty)(_ |+| _)
// res1: Map[String,Double] = Map()
```

Comment: I made the desired changes of making it val and immutable and I'm trying to use reduce but i get the following exception :value |+| is not a member of Map[String,Double]. [This] (https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/766) here says "Double is not associative due to its hardware representation." What does this mean?

Comment: @hbabbar It means that because of how `Double` are represented `(a +b) + c` is not always equal to `a + (b + c)`. For a workaround see my answer with some additions to this answer.