# Scalaz cannot resolve symbol |+|, unused import statement

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalaz

I'm trying to use the Scalaz operator |+| as suggested in this question

[Best way to merge two maps and sum the values of same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key)

```
import scalaz._

val map1 = Map("a" -> 1,"b" -> 2, "c" -> 5)
val map2 = Map("a" -> 3,"b" -> 4)
val map3 = map1 |+| map2
```

Intellij says |+| cannot resolve symbol and import.scalaz._ is unused.
The SBT seems to be working just fine and the import statement looks valid but here it is just in case.

```
"org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.6"
```

Whats happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import both `scalaz._` and `Scalaz._`

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

notice `S` in `Scalaz`is Uppercase letter in the second import

*Scala REPL*

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val map1 = Map("a" -> 1,"b" -> 2, "c" -> 5)
map1: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 5)

scala> val map2 = Map("a" -> 3,"b" -> 4)
map2: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 3, "b" -> 4)

scala> val map3 = map1 |+| map2
map3: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 4, "b" -> 6, "c" -> 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.