# How do you multiply values in one map with the values in another?

Tags: scala

If you have two maps (one is mutable, the other is immutable), how would you multiply the values of one with the corresponding values of the other?

For example:

```
val testA = scala.collection.mutable.Map("£2" -> 3, "£1" -> 0, 
                  "50p" -> 4, "20p" -> 0, "10p" -> 0, "5p" -> 0)
val testB = scala.collection.immutable.Map("£2" -> 2, "£1" -> 1, 
                  "50p" -> 0.5, "20p" -> 0.2, "10p" -> 0.1, "5p" -> 0.05)
```

Expecting a result of:

```
val total = scala.collection.immutable.Map("£2" -> 6, "£1" -> 0, 
                  "50p" -> 2, "20p" -> 0, "10p" -> 0, "5p" -> 0)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to map each value to that value multiplied by the lookup result on `testB` (or 1.0, if none found)

```
testA.map { case (k, v) => (k, v * testB.getOrElse(k, 1.0)) }
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key - same question (with addition instead of multiplication), with some other interesting answers (specifically, using Scalaz's Semigroup)