# Scala Map merge and sum the value when the key is same

Tags: scala, dictionary

How can I merge maps like below:

```
val a = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
val b = Map("b" -> 3, "c" -> 6)
```

after merge：

```
var c = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 val a = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2) 
 val b = Map("b" -> 3, "c" -> 6)
 val c = a.map {
   case (key, value) => key -> (value + b.getOrElse(key, 0))
 } ++ b.filterKeys(bKey => !a.keySet.contains(bKey))
```

This should work but if it doesn't... I just found I think your question is a duplicate: [Best way to merge two maps and sum the values of same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key)

In there you see that other possible solutions are...

```
(map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet).map {i=> (i,map1.getOrElse(i,0) + map2.getOrElse(i,0))}.toMap


map1 ++ map2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k,0)) }

val m1 = Map(1 -> 1.0, 3 -> 3.0, 5 -> 5.2)
val m2 = Map(0 -> 10.0, 3 -> 3.0)
val merged = (m2 foldLeft m1) (
  (acc, v) => acc + (v._1 -> (v._2 + acc.getOrElse(v._1, 0.0)))
)
```

And more

Comment: It seems to work.But when I try to define this as a funcxtion, got erros as follows:error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
    [INFO]   (x: Double)Double <and>
    [INFO]   (x: Float)Float <and>
    [INFO]   (x: Long)Long <and>
    [INFO]   (x: Int)Long <and>
    [INFO]   (x: Char)Long <and>
    [INFO]   (x: Short)Long <and>
    [INFO]   (x: Byte)Long <and>
    [INFO]   (x: String)String
    [INFO]  cannot be applied to (AnyVal)
    [INFO]   a.map {
   case (key, value) => key -> (value + b.getOrElse(key, 0))
 } ++ b.filterKeys(bKey => !a.keySet.contains(bKey))

Comment: Can you copy and paste the code you are defining as a function

Comment: This is the defination:    val mergeMap = udf(
                (a:Map[String, Long], b:Map[String, Long]) => a.map { case (key, value) => key -> (value + b.getOrElse(key, 0)) } ++ b.filterKeys(bKey => !a.keySet.contains(bKey))
        )

Comment: `def mapMerge(map1: Map[String, Long], map2: Map[String, Long]): Map[String, Long] = {
    val map1Keys = map1.keySet
    map1.map {
      case (key, value) => key -> (value + map2.getOrElse(key, 0))
    } ++ map2.filterKeys(map2Key => !map1Keys.contains(map2Key))
  }`

Comment: The same errors. It seems a type error.

Comment: `def mapMerge(map1: Map[String, Long], map2: Map[String, Long]): Map[String, Long] = { val map1Keys = map1.keySet map1.map { case (key, value) => key -> (value + map2.getOrElse(key, 0L)) } ++ map2.filterKeys(map2Key => !map1Keys.contains(map2Key)) }` Try now. The reason why was because there wasn't an L next to the 0, so it didn't know which + method to use

Comment: yeah, it works! Thank you very much！

Comment: no problem :)   ;;;