# Check if RDD contains same key and merge them if yes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD[(String,Map[String,Int])],

```
   [("A",Map("acs"->2,"sdv"->2,"sfd"->1),("B",Map("ass"->2,"fvv"->2,"ffd"->1)),("A"),Map("acs"->2,"sdv"->2,"sfd"->1)]
```

I want to merge the elements with same key as,

```
    [("A",Map("acs"->4,"sdv"->4,"sfd"->2),("B",Map("ass"->2,"fvv"->2,"ffd"->1))]
```

How to do this is in scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient approach would be to use `reduceByKey` to aggregate the `Map` (in the accumulator) by summing the values of matched keys:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A", Map("acs"->2, "sdv"->2, "sfd"->1)),
  ("B", Map("ass"->2, "fvv"->2, "ffd"->1)),
  ("A", Map("acs"->2, "sdv"->2, "sfd"->1))
))

rdd.reduceByKey( (acc, m) =>
  acc ++ m.map{ case (k, v) => (k, acc.getOrElse(k, 0) + v) }
).collect

// res1: Array[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int])] = Array(
//   (A,Map(acs -> 4, sdv -> 4, sfd -> 2)),
//   (B,Map(ass -> 2, fvv -> 2, ffd -> 1))
// )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define `mapSum` (see [merge two maps and sum values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080321/1240268)):

```
def mapSum[T](map1: Map[T, Int], map2: Map[T, Int]): Map[T, Int] = map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k,0)) }
```

Then you can groupBy and reduce (similar to your other question):

```
@ rdd.groupBy(_._1).map(_._2.reduce((a, b) => (a._1, mapSum(a._2, b._2)))).collect
res11: Array[(String, Map[String, Int])] = Array(
  ("A", Map("acs" -> 4, "sdv" -> 4, "sfd" -> 2)),
  ("B", Map("ass" -> 2, "fvv" -> 2, "ffd" -> 1))
)
```