# Reduce and sum tuples by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, reduce

In my Spark Scala application I have an RDD with the following format:

```
(05/05/2020, (name, 1))
(05/05/2020, (name, 1))
(05/05/2020, (name2, 1))
...
(06/05/2020, (name, 1))
```

What I want to do is group these elements by date and sum the tuples that have the same "name" as key.

**Expected Output:**

```
(05/05/2020, List[(name, 2), (name2, 1)]),
(06/05/2020, List[(name, 1)])
...
```

In order to do that, I am currently using a `groupByKey` operation and some extra transformations in order to group the tuples by key and calculate the sum for those that share the same one.

For performance reasons, I would like to replace this `groupByKey` operation with a `reduceByKey` or an `aggregateByKey` in order to reduce the amount of data transferred over the network.

However, I can't get my head around on how to do this. Both of these transformations take as parameter a function between the values (tuples in my case) so I can't see how I can group the tuples by key in order to calculate their sum.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can merge your Tuples using `reduceByKey`:

```
/**
File /path/to/file1:
15/04/2010  name
15/04/2010  name
15/04/2010  name2
15/04/2010  name2
15/04/2010  name3
16/04/2010  name
16/04/2010  name

File /path/to/file2:
15/04/2010  name
15/04/2010  name3
**/

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val filePaths = Array("/path/to/file1", "/path/to/file2").mkString(",")

val rdd: RDD[(String, (String, Int))] = sc.textFile(filePaths).
  map{ line =>
    val pair = line.split("\\t", -1)
    (pair(0), (pair(1), 1))
  }

rdd.
  map{ case (k, (n, v)) => (k, Map(n -> v)) }.
  reduceByKey{ (acc, m) =>
    acc ++ m.map{ case (n, v) => (n -> (acc.getOrElse(n, 0) + v)) }
  }.
  map(x => (x._1, x._2.toList)).
  collect
// res1: Array[(String, List[(String, Int)])] = Array(
//   (15/04/2010, List((name,3), (name2,2), (name3,2))), (16/04/2010, List((name,2)))
// )
```

Note that the initial mapping is needed because we want to merge the Tuples as elements in a `Map`, and [reduceByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@reduceByKey(func:(V,V)=%3EV):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]) for RDD[K, V] requires the same data type `V` before and after the transformation:

```
def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) => V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

Comment: Your solution, although minimal doesn't seem to work. In that particular simple example which you provided it works. However, i read my input data from different files and for a strange reason these computations are only applied on the data taken from the first file.

Comment: I further tested this and it seems that when I am reading 2 different files (through sc.textfile) the number of partitions is 2. It seems that your approach operates only on the first partition. When I repartition my rdd to 1, it works, however this is not optimal.

Comment: @matrix, I'm not able to replicate the said problem.  Also tested the code with a larger RDD explicitly loaded into multiple partitions and it aggregated across the partitions as expected.  As you can see, the proposed solution simply uses common RDD methods `map` and `reduceByKey` in their simplest form.  Could you share a minimal version of the exact code (and sample data if possible) that led to the erroneous result?

Comment: I created a small app that reproduces the issue. (In the comments you'll see the data for each file) You can find it here: https://pastebin.com/E7s2zcw4

Comment: @matrix, thanks for the sample code and data that is able to demonstrate the said problem.  The anomaly appears to be caused by the function in `reduceByKey` not being processed properly across partitions in some cases.  The problem is so subtle that it wouldn't necessarily surface simply by having multiple partitions; and when it does surface it's also not that only the first partition is processed.  I'm at this point inclined to consider it a bug.  Rewriting the function to using `Map ++ Map` operation, rather than `Map + element`, seems to fix the problem.  Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `.aggeregateBykey()` can be used as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

def merge(map: HashMap[String, Int], element: (String, Int)) = {
 if(map.contains(element._1)) map(element._1) += element._2 else map(element._1) = element._2
 map
}

val input = sc.parallelize(List(("05/05/2020",("name",1)),("05/05/2020", ("name", 1)),("05/05/2020", ("name2", 1)),("06/05/2020", ("name", 1))))

val output = input.aggregateByKey(HashMap[String, Int]())({
  //combining map & tuple   
  case (map, element) => merge(map, element) 
}, {
  // combining two maps 
  case (map1, map2) => {
   val combined = (map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet).map { i=> (i,map1.getOrElse(i,0) + map2.getOrElse(i,0)) }.toMap
   collection.mutable.HashMap(combined.toSeq: _*)
  } 
}).mapValues(_.toList)
```

credits: [Best way to merge two maps and sum the values of same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076128/best-way-to-merge-two-maps-and-sum-the-values-of-same-key)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the RDD to a DataFrame and just use a groupBy with sum, here is one way to do it

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(StructField("date", StringType, false) :: StructField("name", StringType, false) ::  StructField("value", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)

val rd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("05/05/2020", ("name", 1)),
("05/05/2020", ("name", 1)),
("05/05/2020", ("name2", 1)),
("06/05/2020", ("name", 1))))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rd.map{ case (a, (b,c)) => Row(a,b,c)},schema)
df.show

+----------+-----+-----+
|      date| name|value|
+----------+-----+-----+
|05/05/2020| name|    1|
|05/05/2020| name|    1|
|05/05/2020|name2|    1|
|06/05/2020| name|    1|
+----------+-----+-----+

val sumdf = df.groupBy("date","name").sum("value")
sumdf.show

+----------+-----+----------+
|      date| name|sum(value)|
+----------+-----+----------+
|06/05/2020| name|         1|
|05/05/2020| name|         2|
|05/05/2020|name2|         1|
+----------+-----+----------+
```